# Attempting to set a non-NULL- able column's value to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting attempting to set a non-NULL- able column's value to NULL

> error when I use FOR XML PATH('')

Code:

```
select  
    fdp.POLICYNUMBER,
    fdp.INSUREDNAME,
    fdp.OWNERNAME,
    fdp.AGENCYCODE, 
    p.WFWORKSTEPNAME,
    fdpc.NIGO,
    fdpc.NIGOREASON,
    d.NIGOREQUIREMENT,
    wci.WCSTATUS,
    wci.DATECOMPLETED,
    fdCI.NEWUNDERWRITINGUSER,
    fdr.NBAMOUNT 
into
    #t
from
    PINewBusiness p 
join
   FDPolicyDetails fdp on SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY, 9, LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = fdp.PARENT_CASEID 
                       and (p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'PendingRequirements' or 
                            p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'FollowUpRequirements' )
join
    FDProcessing fdpc on SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY, 9, LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = fdpc.PARENT_CASEID
join
    FDRounting fdr on SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY, 9, LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = fdr.PARENT_CASEID
cross apply
    (select NIGOREQUIREMENT + ', ' 
     from FDNIGORequirements nr 
     where nr.PARENT_CASEID = fdpc.PARENT_CASEID 
     for xml path('')) D (NIGOREQUIREMENT)
--join FDNIGORequirements nr on SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY, 9, LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = nr.PARENT_CASEID
cross apply
    (select NIGOREQUIREMENT + ', ' 
     from FDNIGORequirements nr 
     where nr.PARENT_CASEID = SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY,9,LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) 
     for xml path('')) D (NIGOREQUIREMENT)
join
    (select max(CREATEDDATETIME) as CREATEDDATETIME, PARENT_CASEID 
     from FDWelcomeCall 
     group by PARENT_CASEID ) wc on fdr.PARENT_CASEID = wc.PARENT_CASEID
join
    FDWelcomeCall wci on wci.PARENT_CASEID = wc.PARENT_CASEID 
                      and wci.CREATEDDATETIME = wc.CREATEDDATETIME
join
    FDCaseInformation fdCI on SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY, 9, LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = fdCI.PARENT_CASEID
where
    p.WFSTEPENTRYTIME >= @sdate 
    and p.WFSTEPENTRYTIME <= @edate
order by 
    p.WFFLOWENTRYTIME desc
```

Comment: Hi please share your #t table definition ddl

Comment: You are probably thinking that `cross apply` will eliminate rows where the subquery does not return anything. But because you are using `for xml`, instead you are getting a `null` XML value which you are apparently then inserting into an outer table.

Comment: @GSerg how can I solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the rows with NULL values you must replace the nulls in the column that gives you the error, to do so you can use:

```
SELECT COALESCE([MyColumn],__ReplacementValue__) AS [MyColumn] FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT ISNULL([MyColumn],__ReplacementValue__) AS [MyColumn] FROM MyTable
```

You can use one of them in the inner or outer SELECT.

Otherwise, if the row should not exist if that value is null you must filter it out by adding a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE [MyColumn] IS NOT NULL
```